# Incremental update of BigQuery table using Dataform with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dataform

I have created a BigQuery table using the following code in Dataform:

```
config {
  type: "table",
  bigquery: {
    partitionBy: "DATE(timestamp)",
    clusterBy: ["itemName",'StoreName']
  }
}

SELECT DATE(timestamp) as Dates, *
from `<mytable in BQ>`
where storeName like "%XXXX%"

${when(incremental(), `where timestamp > (select max(timestamp) from ${self()})`)}
```

That work just fine. But, I want to schedule daily updates doing the following thing:

```
config {
  type: "incremental",
  bigquery: {
    partitionBy: "DATE(timestamp)",
    clusterBy: ["itemName",'StoreName']
  }
}

SELECT DATE(timestamp) as Dates, *
from `<mytable in BQ>`
where storeName like "%XXXX%"

${when(incremental(), `where timestamp > (select max(timestamp) from ${self()})`)}
```

but this doesn't work as I get the following error:

[image]

So, from the error message I realize that what I am doing actually creates 2 where statements. I therefore tried to have the filter inside the incremental clause with an AND but this doesn't work either. I have found an addition to the incremental update of tables called `updatePartitionFilter`  but I am not sure whether it can be used for this.

```
config {
  type: "incremental",
  bigquery: {
    partitionBy: "DATE(timestamp)",
    updatePartitionFilter:
        "storeName like '%XXXX%'",
    clusterBy: ["itemName",'StoreName']
  }
}

SELECT DATE(timestamp) as Dates, *
from `<mytable in BQ>`
${when(incremental(), `where timestamp > (select max(timestamp) from ${self()})`)}
```

Is this the right way to do this? Since I am updating by day, I have no way of testing this before tomorrow. I don't have time to wait.

Comment: As per this doc here -->https://docs.dataform.co/guides/datasets/incremental#a-merge-example. You are kind of on the right path, but shouldn't you add UNIQUEKey as mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on Serge's answer, the `${when(incremental(), 'WHERE ..,')}` block simply appends the specified `WHERE` clause to the executed SQL. A helpful video explaining how the executed SQL is compiled can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3OmoSKZj8Y).

In your initial example, you already had a `WHERE` clause specified, so this was adding a second `WHERE` clause, resulting in the error in the executed query where it was unexpectedly finding the keyword `WHERE`.

The solution that Serge has proposed works, as this will add the `WHERE` clause and then the extra criteria with `AND` afterwards, which (when incrementing the table) will compile the below:

```
INSERT INTO `<target_table>`
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS Dates, *
FROM `<mytable in BQ>`
WHERE timestamp > (select max(timestamp) from `<target_table>`
AND storeName like "%XXXX%"
```

However I believe this would fail to include the filter on `storeName` for the initial build of the `<target_table>`, as when the table doesn't yet exist, the `${when(incremental(),'WHERE ...')}` clause is not appended. This would leave the compiled SQL as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `<target_table>` AS
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS Dates, *
FROM `<mytable in BQ>`
-- NOTE NO `WHERE` CLAUSE
```

A better way could be to change the `WHERE` to an `AND` in the `${when(incremental(),...)}` logic, as below:

```
config {
  type: "incremental",
  bigquery: {
    partitionBy: "DATE(timestamp)",
    clusterBy: ["itemName",'StoreName']
  }
}

SELECT DATE(timestamp) as Dates, *
from `<mytable in BQ>`
where storeName like "%XXXX%"

${when(incremental(), `AND timestamp > (select max(timestamp) from ${self()})`)}
```

This would execute the query successfully with the filter on `storeName` when creating the table initially, and then for any subsequent runs would execute the below compiled SQL to increment:

```
INSERT INTO `<target_table>`
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS Dates, *
FROM `<mytable in BQ>`
WHERE storeName like "%XXXX%"
AND timestamp > (select max(timestamp) from `<target_table>`
```

Hopefully that makes sense! (This is my first ever response on SO so apologies for any dodgy formatting...)

Edit: Amended the second code block example as I hadn't realised that Serge had included the filter on `storeName` within the `${when(incremental(),...)}` config.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this.

```
updatePartitionFilter:
        "storeName like '%XXXX%'",
```

is not the way to do this as it influences the partitioning, not what is selected.

What one actually needs to do is to move the second clause within the `incremental`statement at the end of the query:

```
config {
  type: "incremental",
  bigquery: {
    partitionBy: "DATE(timestamp)",
    clusterBy: ["itemName",'StoreName']
  }
}

SELECT DATE(timestamp) as Dates, *
from `<mytable in BQ>`
${when(incremental(), `where timestamp > (select max(timestamp) from ${self()}) and storeName like '%XXXX%'`)}
```

In fact,any other filter needs to be inserted there.

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) as Dates, *
from `<mytable in BQ>`
${when(incremental(), `where timestamp > (select max(timestamp) from ${self()}) 
and storeName like '%XXXX%' 
and itemName = 'My little pony'`)}
```